# React serving images from Public folder VS importing them

Tags: reactjs, image, responsive-design, next.js, srcset

I know there are several options where to store and how to serve images in react.
two options are:

1. store the image in public folder and then use it like this:

   `<img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/someImage.jpg'} />`
2. store the image somewhere else in the project, import it and use it like this:

   `import image from '../../assets/images/someImage.jpg'`

   `<img src={image} />`

I need now to create an img tag with **srcSet** with few images that the correct size will be shown according to screen width.
In order to avoid adding many lines of code (4 or 5 sizes for each image) for importing the images as I do today (I am using the second method as described above), I think maybe to move them to the public folder then I wont need to import many versions and also mention all those versions in the srcSet.

My question is

what will be the differences between serving images using the first vs the second methods I wrote above?

**and which option will you work with?
in case you have many images and want to set `srcSet` with few versions to each image?**

Comment: Assuming you're using `webpack`, it depends on its configuration.  Most likely, the second will cause the image to be converted into inline binary data in the rendered HTML.  You can inspect the image element in the browser to see.  Inline binary images avoid a second request to the server to load the image, but increase bundle size, especially if the image is used in multiple places.

Comment: thank you, so which option will you work with? I have added in the end the summery question

Comment: That's a judgement call and it depends on your requirements.  srcSet should work with either approach.  Whichever is easier for you to code is what I'd start with, then you can assess performance concerns.

Comment: great, and in performance concerns? which one is better?

Comment: I don't know.  That's what you'll need to find out.  It's part of your job as a good programmer.  Generally, if you don't notice a performance problem, then there isn't a performance problem (yet).